# QRubberBand not drawing

Tags: qt

my code as follows, i followed the example on the qt doc but nothing is being drawn on my widget, any one knows whats wrong? Thanks!

```
 ui.axWidget_X->installEventFilter(this);

 bool qtTest::eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event)
{
  if((QAxWidget *)obj == ui.axWidget_X && ((QMouseEvent*)event)->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
{

   if(event->type()== QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
         origin =   ((QMouseEvent*)event)->Pos();

    if (!rubberBand)
        rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin, QSize()));
    rubberBand->show();

    return true;
    }else if(event->type()== QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {
      rubberBand->hide();
          //

    return true;
    }else if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
         rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin, ((QMouseEvent*)event)>Pos()).normalized());
        return true;
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your mousemove event handler is placed within the left button click checking parent condition. Since for a MouseMove event "((QMouseEvent*)event)->button() == Qt::LeftButton" will return false, the MouseMove event is not handled..

Solution:

```
  Move the "else if" part handling MouseMove outside the if condition.
```